# Iframe for Displaying Banner with hyperlink Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, banner

I setup a simple banner ads with a hyperlink using javascript code from - [text](https://owlcation.com/stem/JavaScript-Banner-Rotator)

**network-banner-ads.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Network Banner Ads">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Network Banner Ads</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ad-container"></div>
    
<script src="/network-banner-ads.js" async></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The banners work - [text](https://earthlike1.com/network-banner-ads.html)

[Banner Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNy5A.jpg)

But when places it on another webpage or website using a basic Iframe it doesn't work.  (I did have it working but it stopped).

I placed the Iframe on this webpage with the code below - [text](https://earthlike1.com/banners.html)

**banners.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Banners</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<iframe src="https://earthlike1.com/network-banner-ads.html" width="625" height="175" title="Network Banner Ads"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Banner Not Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztdhV.jpg)

Why is the Iframe not showing displaying the banners?

How to make this iframe work so the banners can be displayed on other websites.